# Is there any way to hide the incomplete part on the left hand side of the Calendar List View in SharePoint Page?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-office, office-js

In a SharePoint Page, I have added a Calendar App, on the left-hand side of the Calendar View:

[image: Calendar view]

I would need to hide the highlighted part as it is a incomplete calendar in this View.

Would need to hide it. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
<style>
tr>th:first-child {
display:none
}
</style>
```

Test result:
[image]